# Java - Append to ArrayList Elements of a File

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

In Java, I am reading data from a CSV file such as:

```
a,b,c,d
hello,hi,hey, 
bye,ciao,adios,
z,y,x,w
```

What I want is to create an arrayList of Strings such as:

```
["a hello bye z", "b hi ciao y", "c hey adios x", "d w"]
```

The file is very unstructured, so each line does not have the same number of elements. I feel an arrayList will be the best option.My pseudocode so far is:

```
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();    

        for(each line){

            for(int i = 0; i < numberOfElementsInEachLine; i++){

                list.add(i, list.get(i) + getLineElement(i));
            }
         }
```

What is the best way to achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: `list.add(i, list.get(i) + getLineElement(i));` What do you think this line is supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

Method add on List does not replace element at specific index but add a new one.
[Javadoc for List interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add(int,%20E))

I suggest to use StringBuilder instance and method append

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should change:

```
list.add(i, list.get(i) + getLineElement(i));
```

to:

```
list.get(i) = "" + list.get(i) + getLineElement(i);
```

Because a add() method of arraylist will add an new element into the list.

Comment: Can I even use list.get(i) in the first iteration of both loops? Doesn't it return a NULL?

Comment: If there is nothing in ith position of list then you will get **IndexOutOfBoundException** for executing list.get(i), see the docs here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get(int)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want each column of the file be an array list. You need to do the following:

- Create a list of array list that is empty initially
- Open file in reading mode
- Read line by line until not null
- For each line, split it by comma (i assume comma is the seperator)
- Loop through chunks separated by comma
- If empty value found then skip it
- Check if list of `List<String>` contains a `List<String>` in location ith, if yes then retrieve that `List<String>` and add the chunks[ith] to it and add it back to main list (in ith position replacing the old `List<String>`)
- If `main` list do not contain a `List<String>` in ith position then create a new `List<String>`, add chunk[i] to it and then add it to main list.

Applying the above to your input

Looping through `a,b,c,d` for `List<String>` is added to `List<List<String>>` structure each containing `a,b,c and d` respectively.

Looping through second line `hello, hi and hey` first three List is retrieved from `List<List<String>>` structure and updated and stored again.

Assume that your third line contains `1,2,3,4,5` (one more than above two lines). The loop will find 4 `List<String>` from `List<List<String>>` and updated them with 1,2,3 and 4 respectively but, what about 5? Well `List<List<String>>` contains no `List<String>` in 5 because other lines were 4 chunks only, so create a new `List<String>` and add 5 to it and then add it to `List<List<String>>`.

Here is a sample code that actually does what I have described above. I assume that you wanted something in `ArrayList` line.

```
//list that stores list of strings
        List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<List<String>>(); 
        try {
            //open file in read mode, change the file location 
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\test_java\\content.txt")); 
            String line = ""; 
            //read each line as long as line != null which indicates end of file
            while((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                //split the line into chunks using comma as seperator
                String[] chunks = line.split(","); 
                //loop through chunks of vlaues
                for(int i = 0; i < chunks.length; i++) {
                    //if chunks[i] is not empty
                    if(chunks[i].trim().length() > 0) {
                        //there is a List<String> in list.get(i) so get the List<String> update it and put it back
                        if(list.size() > i) {
                            List<String> temp = list.get(i); 
                            temp.add(chunks[i]); 
                            list.remove(i); 
                            list.add(i, temp);
                        } else {
                            //there was no list in list.get(i) so create a new List<String> and add it there
                            List<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>(); 
                            temp.add(chunks[i]); 
                            list.add(temp);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //close read stream
            br.close();
        } catch(Exception e){ 
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }

        //print the list
        for(List<String> l: list) {
            System.out.println(l); 
        }
```

Output of the input file you provided in question

```
[[a, hello, bye, z], [b, hi, ciao, y], [c, hey, adios, x], [d, w]]
```

If you want to get an exact output as shown in the question then you can iterate through the `List<List<String>>` and take each `List<String>` create a singe string from its elements pre and postfixing it with double quote. See below, I have used Java 8's iterator to iterate through `List<String>` and create StringBuilder obj.

```
String[] s = new String[list.size()];
int i = 0; 
for(List<String> l: list) {
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder("\""); 
    //java 8 loop through list and for each element add it to StrinbBuilder obj
    l.stream().forEach(e -> b.append(e + " "));
    b.append("\"");
    s[i++] = b.toString();
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s));
```

Above will give you

```
["a hello bye z ", "b hi ciao y ", "c hey adios x ", "d w "]
```